# Importing CSV file in ArcGIS Pro ArcPy script using relative paths

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-toolbox

I have a CSV file in my toolbox folder. I would like to import the CSV file into my arcpy script to run in conjunction with my arcpy script.

Folder structure:

- src

  - data

    - my_csv.csv
  - mytoolbox.pyt

How would I import the my_csv.csv into the mytoolbox.pyt?

I receive an error when I try running through ArcGIS Pro GUI.:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ../data/my_csv.csv`

code:

```py
    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        # Open layer and process!!
        arcpy.AddMessage(os.getcwd()) # output is AppData folder for windows
        df_cat_codes = pd.read_csv("../data/my_csv.csv")
        arcpy.AddMessage("CSV shape: ", df_cat_codes.shape)

        return
```

I am using the template from: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/a-template-for-python-toolboxes.htm

Comment: Always use `os.path` to manipulate paths.

Comment: See what `__file__` points to (I'm not sure in the case of a *.pyt)

Comment: *I receive errors* What errors? Please include all relevant information in your question.

Comment: Isn't the relative path to the csv just `data/my_csv.csv`? According to your bullet points, mytoolbox.pyt and data are at the same level.

Comment: When I check the current location using os.getcwd() (after adding toolbox in Arc Pro), the path join when running in Arc Pro is something like `.\AppData\Local\Temp\ArcGISProTemp82956\`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
scriptsPath=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

will give you path to toolbox (works with tbx), so join 'data' and scriptsPath to get location of csv file.